# ResourceBundle is unable to load properties file from package inside a webapp

Tags: java, maven, resourcebundle

I am working on refactoring a huge collection of code in an enterprise-scaled application.

The first step I want to take is to localize the log messages, so I decided to use the [`StringManager`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager.java) that I saw when I was reading the source code of Apache Tomcat.

The basic idea is to declare a file named `LocalString.properties` in the packages and define log messages in them. So in a way, this *localizes* the Strings to scope of that package only, so that it looks like:

```
Application
`----src
|    `----main
|         `----java
|              `----package
|                   `----BusinessAction.java
|                   `----LocalStrings.properties
`----pom.xml
```

And an object of this `StringManager` is instantiated as:

```
private static final StringManager sm = StringManager.getManager("package");
```

---

This is constructor of the `StringManager` class.

```
/**
 * Creates a new StringManager for a given package. This is a
 * private method and all access to it is arbitrated by the
 * static getManager method call so that only one StringManager
 * per package will be created.
 *
 * @param packageName Name of package to create StringManager for.
 */
private StringManager(String packageName) {
    String bundleName = packageName + ".LocalStrings";
    try {
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, Locale.getDefault());
    } catch( MissingResourceException ex ) {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if( cl != null ) {
            try {
                bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                        bundleName, Locale.getDefault(), cl);
            } catch(MissingResourceException ex2) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }
    // Get the actual locale, which may be different from the requested one
    if (bundle != null) {
        locale = bundle.getLocale();
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine when used in a standalone application, but is causing issues when used in a web application.

I don't understand why the bundle fails to load on the first hand, but in the catch block, I can definitely tell that it is because the classloader is an instance of `WebappClassloader`.

What mistake I am making here? Also, what would be the good ways to load this property file?

---

## Edit

The problem here is with the Maven build. Maven process all resources in `src/main/resources` and ignores the ones in `src/main/java`. So in the end, the compiled application did't had the `LocalStrins.properties` file where it was supposed to be.

Solved it by creating `package` in `src/main/resources` and putting the file in there.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto the ResourceBundle object is always null... I guess this might happen as the application is not able to locate the properties file.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I figured it out. The file is missing in the compiled webapp. Maven does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it fails is simply that the LocalStrings.properties file is not in your war file. In a Maven project, resources are supposed to be under `src/main/resources`. Not `src/main/java`. Maven will simply ignore resources under `src/main/java`, so they won't be in the built webapp at all, and thus won't be available at runtime.

Comment: I know this property of maven, but these property files are supposed to exist in packages...

Comment: So what? Just use the same directory structure under src/main/resources. In the end, everything will be merged into the WEB-INF/classes directory of your webapp.

Comment: Actually we have modified how that application is built. There is a mojo which assembles it into the tomcat instance after the compiler finishes compiling it.

Comment: Then check that the LocalStrings.properties file is where it's supposed to be in the compiled webapp.

Comment: Exactly. The file is missing in the compiled webapp. Can you please edit your answer so that it includes that point as well? I think that would make it easier for newcomers to look for solution.